Can you make a random numpy.float128?
I want to make a random array of type numpy.float128s. This is not valid:
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random(100, dtype=np.float128)  # not valid code

I could do
a = np.random.random(100).astype(np.float128)

but this creates 64 bit floats and then casts them to np.float128 (which is really 80 bit  on my system but that isn't the issue here). So this has the wrong precision.
Is there any way to create an array of random np.float128s in the range 0 to 1?

What error do you get on your first snippet? Would np.longdouble work?

"which is really 80 bit" Not really. This is platform specific. On ARM, it is actually 64 bit. 128-bit Numpy floats are not guaranteed to be bigger than 64-bit (and are also generally significantly slower than 64-bit ones if they are not 64-bit ones).

@YevhenKuzmovych TypeError: random() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype' . You can't specify the dtype

Note: I wrote this assuming Numpy's float128 type are actually IEEE 754 binary128 values.  This isn't the case, so this doesn't seem so useful.  Am leaving the answer in case it's useful to anyone!
A 64bit float has 53 fractional bits, i.e. it can contain 2**53 different states, while a 128bit float has 2**113 states.  Numpy doesn't have 128bit integer types yet.
There are a few ways of combining these to produce a single 128bit float, but if I had to I think I'd probably use a pair of unsigned 64bit integers.  Here's some code that would do this in a similar way to how random 64bit floats are created elsewhere.
import numpy as np

# divides are relatively slow, do this once
RNORM = 1. / np.float128([2**64+1, 2**128])

# put a single 128bit float in rv
state = np.random.randint(2**64, size=2, dtype=np.uint64)
rv = np.sum(state.astype(np.float128) * RNORM)

That said even though the naive way (i.e. generate float64 and casting to float128) "only" gives you 53bits of state, this is still a lot, almost 1e16 states.  Would be interested to know why you think you need more—especially in Python!
Note: See Python or Numpy's codebase for examples of how it creates uniform floats, or read the section titled "Generating uniform doubles in the unit interval" in https://prng.di.unimi.it/ for some explanation.
To demonstrate this is drawing from the correct (uniform) distribution, here's 1 million draws plotted in a histogram with a thousand bins.

The orange lines are 2*sqrt(1000) above/below 1000 (i.e. approx the expected 95% CI).  I get 978 within these bounds, which seems right.

I'm trying to figure out what this code does, and especially what the resulting distribution is.

This assumes IEEE 754 binary128 format, which isn't what the questioner has, and I think is probably not what most systems will have. The questioner's system uses x86 80-bit extended precision format, padded to 128 bits for alignment purposes.

@MSalters it should be uniform, as per np.random.random

@user2357112 huh, interesting! yes, I assumed that the float128 type is a synonym for a 754 binary128 type.  I'd imagine that if it does indeed force the use of the old 80bit x86 FPU (rather than the newer SSE2 units) then performance will kind be pretty bad, as well as not giving much improvement to precision

@SamMason: You generate 128 random bits with randint, and then cast those to FP128? Even ignoring the fact that it's not IEEE FP128, that would generate a lot of NaN, INF values, etcetera, as well as a lot of values <0 and >1. Plus, the distribution is not uniform. Since each bit pattern is equally likely, P(0.25)=P(0.5) but this should differ by a factor of 2.

@MSalters it's casting not reinterpreting the raw bits as floats, so it'll do the appropriate conversions, I don't see any NaNs nor INF values.  I've added a histogram to show it's uniform.

@SamMason: Ah, now I get it. You add two uniform distributions, one with range [0, 1) and one with range [0, 2**-64). The sum of two uniformly distributed variables generally is not uniformly distributed. But since the second distribution is so much smaller, you're not going to notice with only a thousand samples.

@MSalters, yes, also note the one in the range [0, 1) has a step size of 2**-64, so adding them should maintain uniformity as the smaller ones fits into these steps.  it's possible I'm missing something, but I think what I'm doing is valid.  looking at the lower 12 bits (i.e. int(rv * 2**64) % 2**10) I can see they are uniform as well

@SamMason: It's a FP representation, so the step size (np.spacing) is not constant. E.g. np.spacing(0.5)=2*np.spacing(0.25). And for FP64, the step size around 1 would be 2**-53, not 2**-64. It's not the lower bits, it's ~10 bits right in the middle of the 113 bits.

@MSalters the representable FP values might not be uniformly spaced, but that doesn't matter here. what matters is that the PRNG output going in is spaced out to take advantage of upto an 128bit float.  in practice numpy just exposes a long double here, so 64bits of input is enough for all platforms I'm aware of and hence the second value is just a waste.

Random floating-point number generation is tricky, especially a "uniform" distribution. You want P(x) to be approximately equal to np.spacing(x), i.e. P(0.25) = P(0.5) /2 (!)
Now, the spacing of np.float128 (really np.longdouble) is 2048 times smaller than that of np.float64. Hence, you're missing about 99.95% of all possible outputs with your naïve method.
This is easily fixed, though. Given a random x : np.float64, adding np.spacing(x) * np.random.randint(low=0, high=2048) correctly sets the missing 11 bits.

@anatolyg: The spacing of x is nextafter(x)-x, and obviously has to be much smaller than 1 given that 0<=x<1. 2048 is 2**11, the 11 bit difference in mantissa size.

Most random number generation libraries, including numpy.random, don't actually go for the whole spacing-dependent probability stuff described here. For a random float64, NumPy just generates a 53-bit integer and multiplies by 1/2^53. Trying to perform a spacing-dependent adjustment on an input that wasn't generated with a spacing-aware distribution in the first place is going to produce strange results that aren't really what you want.

@user2357112: The basic idea there isn't flawed. If you generate an integer with sufficient bits and multiply it with 2**-N, then rounding to representable values will take care of the spacing. But you need to do that carefully, and 53 bits is not enough. It sort of surprises me,  I'd expect Numpy to document such implementation bugs. (fixing them might break existing code that relied on the non-uniform distribution)

It's not considered a bug. Pretty much no one tries to do the whole spacing-aware thing. I'm not entirely sure whether it's purely for efficiency, or if the statistical properties of the simpler approach are actually more useful.

The spacing-aware approach has some non-obvious awkward statistical properties - for example, I think it produces an extra bias in the low-order bits of 1-x, that you don't get if you generate x with the "53-bit integer times 1/2^53" approach.

@user2357112: Computational statistics is hard, yes. If p(a<=x<b)=1/(b-a), then p( (1-a) > (1-x) > (1-b) != 1/(a-b) due to floating-point representations and rounding. In particular, there are many small numbers x>0 for which (1-x)==1.

@user2357112 Sebastiano Vigna mentions different ways of doing that "spacing aware" generation you're talking about and has some references.  see the bottom of https://prng.di.unimi.it/, it also mentions that you probably need a much better PRNG than is used by default in Numpy
